# JQuery callback method is gone after refreshing the web site

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I hit refresh button on Chrome before my ajax succeeds, a callback `complete: function(data){ doSomething()}` doesn't invoke.

```
function startMockServer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mocks/[[${id}]]/start",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result) {
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            getMockStatusAndUpdateView()
        }
    });
    updateMockServerStatusView("STARTING")
}
```

Is there any way I can keep that ajax callback, even though I refresh the web site?

Comment: When you close/refresh a tab, browser kill all the tasks, so the data transmission would be killed, while you can save a flag in `localstorage` before starting a AJAX request and disable it after success, I see no use of it other than detecting that a AJAX was throttled, anyways you will not be able to recover the response since the request was never completed.

Comment: Not using javascript - you could use a server-side solution, such as websockets and reconnect when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way a callback function can be kept when the website is refreshed.

The function declared on the ajax complete section will only execute when the page, which the request was created, is still active and not reloaded and the ajax call is completed.